# Terraform Loops Not Running

Tags: terraform

I want something like the following in Terraform. How do I construct this? I've tried a few variants and none of it seems to run :(

```
repo_names_list = ["repo1", "repo2", ...]

resource "github_repository" "repo1" {
name = "repo1" # <- look through names here
visibility = "private" <- all other settings the same
}
```

Comment: You should read the docs https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
variable "repo_names_list" {
  type = list(string)
  default = ["repo1", "repo2", ...]
}

resource "github_repository" "repositories" {
  for_each = { for name in var.repo_names_list : name => name }

  name = each.value
  visibility = "private"
  # Add other settings as needed
}
```

Comment: You could simplify this as `foreach = toset(var.repo_names_list)` I think and avoid the map

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to have this format be the declaration for imports as well? Right now when I run terraform plan, it thinks repo2 is a new repo even though it's an existing one.